# How to access a bean set from spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

How can I retrieve a java object which is created from reader (Custom reader in my case) from writer?

I have to keep `count of the records processed` or `skipped` due to exception and all for mail notification after job execution. I don't want to put it in `execution context` as I don't need to persist it.

Can I just set a bean from reader and `autowire` it from writer and use it ?

Comment: Why you are not persisting only relevant info like count in JobContext

Comment: There are lot of values like this which I don’t want to persist, But needed just after the job to send notification to SNS. My job is not restartable. I am already clearing the relevant metadatas after the job for DB overloads.

Comment: I am trying ThreadLocal feture of Java as of now . This will help me here :)

Comment: If you job is not restartable and multiple threads not executing different job instance , then you can simply autowire a singleton bean in both reader and writes and can utilize it

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use same class as reader , writer and then a instance variable can be shared. In fact you use same object for doing stuffs like sending mail by implementing StepExecutionListener in '@afterJob' method after completion of job.

This is good approach if you reader and writer are having simple code. Or you can delegate that code to other class by having separater reader and writer class having actual logic and you can pass your instance variable to those classes. 
You just need to define same class as reader , writer and listener in your configuration.

```
 public class CommitWriter implements ItemWriter<myObject>, ItemReader<myObject> , StepExecutionListener{

private myPojo sharedObject;

//Read method goes here
 public myObjectread() throws Exception{

 }
// Write method goes here
public void write(List<? extends myObject> arg0)
throws Exception {

}


 //After job
 @Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

}

}
```